# Find in raw sql by join table counts

Tags: postgresql, query

Given 3 tables. I need to build SQL query to find two actors who CAST TOGETHER THE MOST and list the titles of those movies. Sort alphabetically

The data for reproducing below:
db-fiddle.com/f/r2Y9CpH8n7MHTeBaqEHe9S/0

```
    create table film_actor
(
    actor_id integer,
    film_id integer
)
;

create table film
(
    film_id integer,
    title varchar
)
;

create table actor
(
    actor_id integer,
    first_name varchar,
    last_name varchar
)
;



INSERT INTO public.film_actor (actor_id, film_id) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO public.film_actor (actor_id, film_id) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO public.film_actor (actor_id, film_id) VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO public.film_actor (actor_id, film_id) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO public.film_actor (actor_id, film_id) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO public.film_actor (actor_id, film_id) VALUES (2, 3);
INSERT INTO public.film_actor (actor_id, film_id) VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO public.film (film_id, title) VALUES (1, 'First');
INSERT INTO public.film (film_id, title) VALUES (2, 'Second');
INSERT INTO public.film (film_id, title) VALUES (3, 'Third');
INSERT INTO public.film (film_id, title) VALUES (4, 'Fourth');
INSERT INTO public.actor (actor_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (1, 'John', 'Snow');
INSERT INTO public.actor (actor_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (2, 'Spider', 'Man');
INSERT INTO public.actor (actor_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (3, 'Mike', 'Kameron');
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @mustaccio How to build described query?

Comment: And what did you try already? You are just dumping like an assignment from somewhere and not showing attempts to do it yourself...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek yeah. here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r2Y9CpH8n7MHTeBaqEHe9S/0

Comment: You should edit your question and add it there. Not as comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shambles, but it's the best I could come up with:

```
select * from (
 select Y.*, max(Y.MRN) over () MMRN
   from (
     select a1,
            max(X.RN) mrn
       from (
         select fa1.actor_id a1,
                fa1.film_id  f1,
                fa2.actor_id a2,
                row_number() over (partition by fa1.actor_id) RN
           from film_actor fa1
           join film_actor fa2 on fa1.film_id = fa2.film_id
                              and fa1.actor_id != fa2.actor_id
       ) X
       group by X.a1
   ) Y
) Z
where Z.mrn = Z.MMRN
;
```

see [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xorTKV7dZfhJsTAdfRBXCL/0)